# Stop ListBox from changing selected item with focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

***For a WPF ListBox with `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"` :***

With `SelectionMode="Single"` when you hit tab the focus moves to the next ListBoxItem and that ListBoxItem is selected automatically.

With `SelectionMode="Multiple"` when you hit tab the focus moves to the next `ListBoxItem` but that `ListBoxItem` is *NOT* selected automatically. (Selected manually using spacebar).

***The Goal:***

Be able to select only a single item (like with `SelectionMode="Single"`) but to be able to move the focus, using tab, without selecting automatically (like with `SelectionMode="Multiple"`).